# Can we restrict function calling once at a time from goroutine

Tags: go

I have following situation

```
wg.Add(1)
go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        select {
            case <-tickerCR.C:
                _ = ProcessCommands()
            case <-ow.quitCR:
                logger.Debug("Stopping ProcessCommands goroutine")
                return
        }
    }
}(&wg)
```

Can I somehow make sure that if ProcessCommands is executing then ignore the next ticker event. Basically I want to avoid parallel execution of ProcessCommands

Comment: `ProcessCommands` is called concurrently from another goroutine? Or is the problem that it returns early while it's still working?

Comment: I just don't want ProcessCommands to be called in parallel.

Comment: The code shown in the question does not call `ProcessCommands` concurrently.   If `tickerCR` is a `time.Ticker`, then extra ticks will be ignored.  Are there other calls to `ProcessCommands` not shown in the question or is the anonymous goroutine function started more than once?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called mutual exclusion. It can be achieved by [Mutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex).

```
var m Mutex

func process() {
    m.Lock()
    defer m.Unlock()
    ProcessCommands()
}
```

Comment: Yes that is one option. But I have lot of these and I will have to create lot of mutex. which Is why I was looking for if there is any other option

Comment: Mutex is fairly cheap.  Don't overthink it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a type that has two fields, a function and a mutex, and when called his, lets say, run method, it locks, defers the unlock and calls the stored function. Afterwards you just need to create instances of that type with the required functions. OOP to the rescue. Remember that functions can be stored in a struct the same way a string would.

```golang
import (
    "sync"
)

type ProtectedCaller struct {
    m sync.Mutex
    f func()
}

func (caller *ProtectedCaller) Call() {
    caller.m.Lock()
    defer caller.m.Unlock()
    caller.f()
}

func ProtectCall(f func()) ProtectedCaller {
    return ProtectedCaller{f: f}
}

var processCommands = ProtectCall(ProcessCommands)
```

Comment: You should have a pointer to a sync.Mutex, otherwise it is copied over.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur under which circunstances? The idea is to use ProtectCall to create the instances, not to modify f directly, and thus each object should have its own Mutex. You can see a working example here: https://play.golang.org/p/iZimtR7at-T

Comment: It is OK now as you are passing pointer to ProtectedCaller.

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo sorry. I also made `Call` an exported method.

Answer (score 1):

There's a semi-standard module **[x/sync/singleflight](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight)**:

How to use:

```
import "golang.org/x/sync/singleflight"

var requestGroup singleflight.Group

// This handler should call it's upstream only once:

http.HandleFunc("/singleflight", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // define request group - each request can have it's specific ID
        // singleflight ensures only 1 request with any given ID is processed at a time
        // also you can have different IDs - to be processed simultaneously  
        // just set ID to "singleflight-1", "singleflight-2", etc
        res, err, shared := requestGroup.Do("singleflight", func() (interface{}, error) {
            fmt.Println("calling the endpoint")
            response, err := http.Get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")

            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return nil, err
            }
            responseData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
            return string(responseData), err
        })

        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        result := res.(string)
        fmt.Println("shared = ", shared)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%q", result)
    })
```

[source](https://dev.to/renatosuero/avoid-duplicated-requests-with-singleflight-53i3)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sync.Once` and prevent multiple calling a function, like this:

```
wg.Add(1)
var once sync.Once
go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        select {
            case <-tickerCR.C:
                   // look at this line, "ProcessCommands" function will call only once
                   once.Do(ProcessCommands)
            case <-ow.quitCR:
                logger.Debug("Stopping ProcessCommands goroutine")
                return
        }
    }
}(&wg)
```